# Durpal 8 on install new module, insert data in new created table

Tags: 8, hooks, installation

I created a new table into the new schema and I want to insert default data into it. 
How can I do this in the module.install file ?

Answer (score 1):

To run tasks when your module is installed, use [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.4.x), e.g.

```
function module_install() {
  \Database::getConnection()->insert(...)->execute();
}
```